# Android wrong Activity opens when receiving simple data (link from chrome)

Tags: android

So it's my first question on the site hope I  expressed my self clearly, and thank in advance for the help.

My application suppose  to receive a link from Chrome, but I want a specific Activity to receive the intent (lets call it Receive_url_activity).
this Activity displays a recyclerView of projects I have, by pressing one of the projects it opens a new Activity (manage_project_activity) that shows all the links this project have.

Now for the problem, it works fine the first time I share link from chrome (receive_url_activity opens and I can choose a project, when pressing one of the projects it opens manage_project_activity and adds the link). 
But the second time I'm trying to do this it opens the the last activity that was open before I left the application instead the one I want.

When I go manually to Receive_url_activity and choose a project it adds the link I shared the first time instead of the link I tried to share the second time.

this in my manifest (I marked the two Activities I talked about):
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".ProjectsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    **<activity
        android:name=".Receive_Url_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_receive__url_">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>**


    <activity
        android:name=".create_new_project_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_new_project_" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Launcher_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    **<activity
        android:name=".project_manager_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_project_manager_" >
    </activity>
</application>**
```

`:

and this is the code of Receive_url_activity (in few words after the basic calls in onCreate I call manageActivity() method, there I deal with all the stuff):

```
public class Receive_Url_Activity extends Activity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ProjectsRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
ProjectsList projects;
String sharedLink;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive__url_);
    manageActivity();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_receive__url_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

public void manageActivity(){
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    sharedLink=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.receive_url_recycler);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ProjectsRecyclerAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //set GestureDetector
    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Receive_Url_Activity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());

            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
                int childNumber=recyclerView.getChildPosition(child);
                int flag=1;
                String link=sharedLink;
                Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                extras.putInt("CHILD_NUMBER",childNumber);
                extras.putInt("FLAG",flag);
                extras.putString("SHARED_LINK",link);
                Intent intent=new Intent(Receive_Url_Activity.this, project_manager_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRAS",extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 2 thing were missing in the code:

1. this one seems to make the difference I add the next label to the Receive_url_activity in the manifest

android:launchMode="singleTask", found this site that explanations the effect on the activity life cycle:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

now the code looks like this :

```
      <activity
        android:name=".Receive_Url_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_receive__url_"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

2. had to override the onNewIntent method in the Receive_url_activity:

   ```
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
   setIntent(intent);
   manageActivity(intent);
   }
   ```